# Never ending for loop with user input

Tags: java, for-loop, input

I am new to java and have just learned how to use user input. I have a for loop that goes through 10 times with user input to ask for a number. If the number is invalid, it should print "Invalid number" and not count towards the increasing for loop. Instead, it just loops forever saying 'Invalid number'.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter number #" + i + " ");
            boolean validInt = scanner.hasNextInt();
            if(validInt){
                int num = scanner.nextInt();
                sum += num;
            } else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Number");
                i--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum was " + sum);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed to add a

```
scanner.nextLine();
```

After the if and else statement to clear the scanner in both situations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are updating the iterator `i` at 2 places.

The better way is to update it according to the condition.

I would also suggest you to make use of wrapper classes for safe integer conversions and handle the exceptions properly like done in the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 1; i<=10; ){

            System.out.println("Enter number #" + i + " ");

            String input = scanner.nextLine();

            try{

                int num = Integer.parseInt(input);
                sum += num;

                i++; // If input is a valid integer, then only update i

            }catch(NumberFormatException e){

                System.out.println("Invalid Number");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum was " + sum);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also can tweak the code using hasNextInt() directly in the while loop.

```
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) { 
  int num = scanner.nextInt();
  sum += num;
}
```